# Trouble linking header-only library with CMake in Clion

Tags: c++, cmake, cygwin, clion

I've been at this for a few hours now, and feeling rather stupid. The library in question is [spdlog](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/), which is just a whole bunch of headers. I am using **CMake** and **cygwin** to compile.

**CMakeLists.txt:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(spdlog_test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

include_directories(E:/Dev/libraries/spdlog)
link_directories(E:/Dev/libraries/spdlog)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(spdlog_test ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(spdlog_test spdlog)
```

All the paths are definetely correct.

**Output** when building:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lspdlog
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/spdlog_test.dir/build.make:94: recipe for target 'spdlog_test.exe' failed
make[2]: *** [spdlog_test.exe] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/spdlog_test.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/spdlog_test.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: The `target_link_libraries` command is to add *linker* libraries, so it's not needed for header-only libraries (which have no linker libraries).

Comment: Ouch. It works now, thank you Sir!

Comment: @ionree it would be great if you could post the solution so people can see how to fix the problem

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude According to cmake documentation [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#interface-libraries) the way to add a dependency on a header-only INTERFACE library is just as ionree did. The only difference is that the example in the documentation used an INTERFACE library defined inside the consumer project(i.e. not IMPORTED) while ionree is using an IMPORTED header-only INTERFACE library. I'm currently having the same problem with a similar situation.

Comment: @MohammedSafwat True that it can be used for header-only libraries, but then the library target have to be explicitly created as an interface library and properly setup. Which does not happen here. And it's not really needed either. Note that the OP isn't using an `IMPORTED` library.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude How spdlog target is defined of course depends on the the cmake config file contents, but typically config files define such targets as IMPORTED and that's what I'm assuming here.

Your concern about the INTERFACE target being properly setup is absolutely to the point since cmake doesn't seem to properly export INTERFACE targets into config file(e.g. using install(EXPORT)) and that's what causes problems later to projects trying to consume these targets.